# Hadoop yarn-webui lost some jquery*.js file?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I configured the yarn according to the hadoop official website. When I visit xxx:8088 website, i got the following information :

This page will not function without javascript enabled. Please enable javascript on your browser.

And i checked the web console,looks like some jquery files missed...

[image: web console Screenshot]

i visited the static path, The type of the jquery file is gz...

[image: static path Screenshot]

why? What should i do? thank you.

hadoop version is 2.7.5,I can't use other versions for some reason.

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try extracting the gz file

Comment: the gz file is in the hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.5.jar which will  be load in the memory   or unzip to a location when the yarn start. I can't find that location,Do you know where it is? Thanks